# Dynamically Created Check Box in Header of Jquery UI Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, stoppropagation

I am creating an accordion from a DB with checkboxes in the headers.  I have seen the solutions that solve the problem of clicking the checkbox without activating the accordion using the click() function, but since I am dynamically creating the accordion, the click() function will not work.  I am at a loss as how to solve the problem of clicking a checkbox in a dynamically generated accordion header.

The problem is that the click event activates the accordion before the on('click') has a chance to run e.stopPropagation.

Any Ideas?

Comment: you try to use this http://api.jquery.com/on/ ?

Comment: Can you share how the checkboxes are created dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you use event propagation to register the event handlers, it is normally attached to the `body` or some elements which is much higher up in the hierarchy. So by the time the events attached to accordion headers will be executed resulting in collapsing/expanding the tab.

Since you are creating the checkbox dynamically, the solution is to add the click event handler preventing propagation to the checkbox after it is created.

Ex:

```
var chk = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox'});
chk.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
chk.appendTo(accordionHeader)
```

Comment: Arun,  Thanks for the quick response, great solution, worked like a charm!